# wordpress - change page link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find out where the header menu links on my WP is located so that i can change the URL of the page.

the link is: **http://www.test.com/blog/category-name/**

and i need to change it to: 
**http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name/**

i need to add 7 category Names as top menu.
 I need all menus like this

menu 1 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name1/**

menu 2 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name2/**

menu 3 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name3/**

menu 4 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name4/**

menu 5 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name5/**

menu 6 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name6/**

menu 7 : **http://www.test.com/blog/category/category-name7/**

However, i do not see anywhere in the menus that i have to change that link. I even looked into the mySQL database wp_posts and tried changing all references. but it still comes up old!??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is in:

Appearance -> Menus

You can add custom links from this page with your URL and the label for the item itself.

If you go Pages -> [your page] as if you were going to edit it, you can change the link at the top just below the title also. I am looking at version 3.3.1 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `settings > Permalink` settings

Make sure your .htaccess is www writable

Comment: .htaccess is www writable.
I m new in WP 
@ settings > Permalink : Can I update Custom Structure like 
category/%category%/  ???

Comment: yes...so now just makthe custom structure in permalinks settings :)

Comment: when I chang in  @ settings > Permalink : Custom Structure = category/%category%/ 

it affect the post I have submitted :(